# How to fix "document is not defined" in node with ejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I just started learning javascript and nodejs(express and ejs) to develop my portfolio. when I run the javascript below, I bump into the error `"document is not defined"`. could someone help me out?
Terminal tells this error.

> ReferenceError: document is not defined
>       at Object. (C:\Users\milkc\WebDevelopment\Practice\sassPortfolio\index.js:21:17)
>       at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:701:30)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
>       at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
>       at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:754:12)
>       at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
>       at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index');
})

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('App listening on port' + port);

})



//Select Dom Item
const menuBtn = document.querySelector('.btn-menu');
const menu = document.querySelector('.menu');
const menuNav = document.querySelector('.menu-nav');
const menuBranding = document.querySelector('.menu-branding');
const navItems = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-item');

// Set Initial state of menu
let showMenu = false;

menuBtn.addEventListener('click', toggleMenu);

function toggleMenu() {
    if (!showMenu) {
        menuBtn.classList.add('close');
        menu.classList.add('show');
        menuNav.classList.add('show');
        menuBranding.classList.add('show');
        navItems.forEach(item => item.classList.add('sjow'));


    } else {
        // Set Menu State
        showMenu = true;

        menuBtn.classList.remove('close');
        menu.classList.remove('show');
        menuNav.classList.remove('show');
        menuBranding.classList.remove('show');
        navItems.forEach(item => item.classList.remove('sjow'));


    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

    <!-- FontAwesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css"
        integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- GoogleFont -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">

    <title>Shintaro Kai</title>
</head>

<body id='bg-img'>
    <header>
        <div class="menu-btn">
            <div class="btn-line"></div>
            <div class="btn-line"></div>
            <div class="btn-line"></div>
        </div>

        <nav class="menu">
            <div class="menu-branding">
                <div class="portrait"></div>
                <ul class="menu-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="" class="nav-link">
                            Home
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="/about.html" class="nav-link">
                            About Me
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="/work.html" class="nav-link">
                            My Work
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="/contact.html" class="nav-link">
                            How to reach me
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <main id="home">
        <h1 class="lg-heading">
            Shintaro <span class="text-secondary"> Kai </span>
        </h1>
        <h2 class="sm-heading">
            Web Developer, Game Designer and Video Contents Creator
        </h2>
        <div class="icons">
            <a href="#!">
                <i class="fab fa-linkedin fa-2x"></i>
            </a>
            <a href="#!">
                <i class="fab fa-facebook fa-2x"></i>
            </a>
            <a href="#!">
                <i class="fab fa-github fa-2x"></i>
            </a>
        </div>
    </main>
    <script src='js/main.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/quiz.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Is your `Select Dom Item` section part of `quiz.js` or some other js?

Answer (score 1):

document exists in browsers only, so below code show be in js file imported by html

```js
//code.js
//Select Dom Item
const menuBtn = document.querySelector('.btn-menu');
const menu = document.querySelector('.menu');
const menuNav = document.querySelector('.menu-nav');
const menuBranding = document.querySelector('.menu-branding');
const navItems = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-item');

// Set Initial state of menu
let showMenu = false;

menuBtn.addEventListener('click', toggleMenu);

function toggleMenu() {
    if (!showMenu) {
        menuBtn.classList.add('close');
        menu.classList.add('show');
        menuNav.classList.add('show');
        menuBranding.classList.add('show');
        navItems.forEach(item => item.classList.add('sjow'));


    } else {
        // Set Menu State
        showMenu = true;

        menuBtn.classList.remove('close');
        menu.classList.remove('show');
        menuNav.classList.remove('show');
        menuBranding.classList.remove('show');
        navItems.forEach(item => item.classList.remove('sjow'));


    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

    <!-- FontAwesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css"
        integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- GoogleFont -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">

    <title>Shintaro Kai</title>
</head>

<body id='bg-img'>
    <header>
        <div class="menu-btn">
            <div class="btn-line"></div>
            <div class="btn-line"></div>
            <div class="btn-line"></div>
        </div>

        <nav class="menu">
            <div class="menu-branding">
                <div class="portrait"></div>
                <ul class="menu-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="" class="nav-link">
                            Home
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="/about.html" class="nav-link">
                            About Me
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="/work.html" class="nav-link">
                            My Work
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="/contact.html" class="nav-link">
                            How to reach me
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <main id="home">
        <h1 class="lg-heading">
            Shintaro <span class="text-secondary"> Kai </span>
        </h1>
        <h2 class="sm-heading">
            Web Developer, Game Designer and Video Contents Creator
        </h2>
        <div class="icons">
            <a href="#!">
                <i class="fab fa-linkedin fa-2x"></i>
            </a>
            <a href="#!">
                <i class="fab fa-facebook fa-2x"></i>
            </a>
            <a href="#!">
                <i class="fab fa-github fa-2x"></i>
            </a>
        </div>
    </main>
    <script src='js/code.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/quiz.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

let's say your main code is index.js

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index');
})

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('App listening on port' + port);

})
```

you should start your server this way:

```sh
node index.js
```

---

Glad to know that you have shared your code through GitHub.

I've just cloned your repo and here is my question:

I see this code

```js
const menuBtn = document.querySelector('.btn-menu');
```

Since I have all your code, I did a search, but I failed to found an match.

So my question is where is this `btn-menu`?

Can you share with us more context, Thanks

Comment: Thank you so much, such a quick reply. I run 'node index.js' in the terminal. However, I still have the same error. 
I really appreciate if I can learn other solutions

Comment: @ShintaroKai can you share with us the folder structure?

Comment: @ShintaroKai One more suggestion, since it's your personal learning project, you may put the code to GitHub, and we can help you do it better.

Comment: Thank you for your kindness. here is my repository.
https://github.com/milkcanbass/portfolio

Comment: @ShintaroKai I'd like to thank you for your co-operation. I will edit my response.

Comment: Sorry for my late reply. thank you so much for saving me. I really appreciate.